# AngularJS remove class delay

Tags: javascript, angularjs

After clicking save from the modal, I want to hide a message after a delay of a few seconds. I need a delay method to remove the class "in" after a few seconds.

**Plunker**: http://plnkr.co/edit/IrIt4G7HzAoi4uh7euVu?p=preview

HTML:
To hide the message, remove the class "in".

```
<div class="alert alert-success text-center fade in" data-ng-show="messageSuccessText">{{messageSuccessText}}</div>
```

This is the function that shows the message:

```
modalInstance.result.then(function (result) {
  $scope.selected = result.item;
  $scope.messageSuccessText = result.message;
}, function () {
  $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
});
```

I need a delay method to remove the class "in" after a few seconds.

**Edit**
Using the suggested $timeout I added this to my HTML message:

```
ng-class="{'in':messageSuccessText}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check out [the $timeout service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

I've modified your code like so:

```
App.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $log, $modal, $timeout) {     
    modalInstance.result.then(function (result) {
      $scope.selected = result.item;
      $scope.messageSuccessText = result.message;

      $timeout(function(e){
        $scope.messageSuccessText = null;
      }, 2000)
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
});
```

Instead of removing the "in" class, i simply set the message text back to null to take advantage of your `ng-show`. I included the `$timeout` service in the list of dependencies to inject, and added a simple callback with a delay of 2000ms using the timeout service. [I forked your plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vk86aMLunJPokydnFlvW?p=preview)